# Extra content at the end of the document XML

Tags: xml, internet-explorer

So I have had to manually create a xml itunes feed because we use mongodb and reactjs for our backend.

basically the issue I am having is that the IE browser is saying

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 23 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

however line 23 is

```
</xml>
```

So I am unsure how it has an error

could anyone please point out where in this xml I have an error. (note I am aware there is no items yet)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:creativeCommons="http://backend.userland.com/creativeCommonsRssModule" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Rant Show</title>
<link>http://rant.show</link>
<language>en-us</language>
<itunes:subtitle>Rant show is a show that allows you to rant about the topics and subjects close to you in an open forum.</itunes:subtitle>
<itunes:author>Radio Media PTY LTD</itunes:author>
<itunes:summary>Join us every week, for a new episode of the Rant Show. Where we talk about the topics that have everyone grasping.</itunes:summary>
<description>Ever felt like a rant but never had friends you could rant with. Well this podcast is all about just that. No topic is off topic and everyone is free to rant about school, work, laws or any subject. We love free speech and thrive on your feedback and suggestions.</description>
<itunes:owner>
<itunes:name>Radio Media PTY LTD</itunes:name>
<itunes:email>podcast@radiomedia.com.au</itunes:email>
</itunes:owner>
<itunes:explicit>yes</itunes:explicit>
<itunes:image href="http://www.example.com/podcast-icon.jpg" />
<itunes:category text="News">
<itunes:category text="News Commentary"/>
</itunes:category>
<atom:link href="http://api.radiomedia.com.au/api-access/shows/rantshow" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
</channel>
</rss>
</xml>
```

Comment: Have You checked for invisible symbols?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should delete the `</xml>` tag. In xml files, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is called **the XML prolog**. In [XML Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp) of w3schools, it says:

> Note: The XML prolog does not have a closing tag! This is not an error. The prolog is not a part of the XML document.

I also find a example of [creating the RSS feed for a iTunes podcast](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/08/create-rss-feed/), you could refer to it if you need.